# Can you run a packet capture (wireshark) while rdped to a server?

Tags: rdp, wireshark

I want to run a packet capture while rdped into a box. I'm pretty sure it won't drop the connection to the server (a server with one nic). I tested on VMs and it seems fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works perfectly fine. The only scenario in which it might not work is if you are using it on a wireless interface that is put into monitor mode and disassociates from the access point that is providing the connection that you are coming through.

You may wish to filter your RDP packets, although my recommendation is actually to capture ALL data, then filter out what you want when you display/analyze it. That way you have some mechanism at least to tell if your connection is interfering with the data that you are actually troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it without problems.

If you wish, you can filter out the RDP connection (tcp port 3389 - src on the server side), since you will capture all the RDP traffic too.